# Connection refused in python firefox selenium webdriver with proxy

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, proxy

There is something wrong with my proxy configuration?  when I execute an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

app.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

myProxy = "46.52.141.46:8080"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('-headless')
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', options=options)

caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
proxy.add_to_capabilities(caps)

driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get('http://ping.eu')
driver.quit()
```

I have tried many ways but the error remains the same, please help